# Best way of class design in Java: An example

Tags: java, class, class-design

Which is the best design for the below problem description :

A 'Student' has **4 Pens** of colors  **Blue**, **Red**, **Green** and **Orange**.

Here is Pen class-

```
Class Pen{
  String color;
  //Getters & setters
  public write(){
    // Write some thing using color
  }

}
```

1st way:

```
Class Studend{
//Here pens are stored in a HashMap with its Color as Key
 Map<String,Pen> pens = new HashMap<String,Pen>();

 Public Student(Pen p){
   pens.put(p.getColor(),p);//Just an example
 }
 //more code here....

}
```

2nd Way:

```
Class Student{
  Pen bluePen;
  Pen greenPen;
  Pen redPen;
  Pen orangePen; 
  //Here all the pens are made as class variables.    

   //Getters and Setters...
}
```

***Note:*** I need to be able iterate over all the pens and do some common operation such as,

```
for(Pen pen: pens){ 
  pen.write();
}
```

which is easier in 1st way.

also, a Pen need to be accessed individually like `student.getRedPen();` which can be done easily in 2nd way.  But in 1st way I need to do every time as

```
 if(student.getPens().containsKey("Red")){ 
  Pen redPen = student.getPens().get("Red");
   //some more code here
 }
```

Which is better one? Are there any other better way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: -> http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In general it really depends on what you plan to do further with those pens, whether student can at some point obtain a 5th Pink pen etc. Both approaches have some advantages, but if you need to iterate over all pens the 2nd approach is really a no go (unless you want to use a reflection - horrible idea). In general those types of questions should go to codereview and not StackOverflow.

Comment: If the number of pens is always 4, then I might be tempted by the option to have a set of variables. However, if that number can be different for different students, then the collection is always the better option.

Comment: @Norbert has the answer in a nutshell here. It's always about future-proofing. What happens if the student acquires two pens of the same colour, or a new pen of a different colour? Instinctively I think you can eliminate the second way.

Comment: @Nobert Its most unlikely that an another pen will be added later. I tried both the approaches but I had to write redundant code much.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
enum PenColor {
    RED,GREEN,BLUE,ORANGE
}

class Student {

    private Pen[] pens;

    public Student() {
        pens = new Pen[4];
        pens[PenColor.RED] = // instantiate red pen
        // etc
    }

    public Pen getPen(PenColor color) {
        return pens[color];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is going to happen when student will be given another red `Pen` at some point? ;)

Comment: This is all good if there is only ever one of each pen. If new pens of the same color are added, blazy's answer is better

Comment: Using enum is good but it becomes again tough if I have to add and remove a particular Pen.

Answer (score 2):

This is a prototype. You can add any other method you'll be needing :

```
public class Student {

private List<Pen> pens = new ArrayList<Pen>();

// Constructor + methods
}

public class Pen {

public enum Color {
    RED, BLUE, GREEN, ORANGE;
}

private Color color;

public Pen(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}

// Getters & setters
public void write() {
    // Write some thing using color
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot iterate over several attributes(option 2), so you have to stick with option 1 if this is nessessary. Also your `get` of a specific colored Pen can be optimized like this:

```
/**
 * returns the Red pen if the student has one, null otherwise.
 */
public Pen getRed(){
    return pens.get("Red");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public class Pen {

     private String color;

     public Pen(){}

     public Pen(String color){
      this.color=color;
     }

     public void write(){
       // writing using color
     }
     public String getColor(){
        return this.color;         
     }

     public void setColor(String color){
      this.color=color;
     }

}

public class Student {

   public static void main(String []args){
     List<Pen> pens=new ArrayList<Pen>();
     pens.add(new Pen("Red"));
     pens.add(new Pen("Green"));
     pens.add(new Pen("Blue"));
     pens.add(new Pen("Orange"));
   }
}
```